# Show that $T(K)\subset K$, that $T$ is an isometry from $K$ to $K$, and that $T$ does not have a fixed point in $K$

Tags: functional-analysis

Here is my problem:

Consider $K=\{f\in L_1[0,1]: 0\leq f\leq 2, \int_0^1fdt=1\}$ and $T:K\to L_1[0,1]$ defined by:

$$Tf(t)=\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    min\{2f(2t),2\} & \quad \text{if $0\leq t\leq 1/2$}\\
    max\{0,2f(2t-1)-2\} & \quad \text{if $1/2\lt t\lt 1$}
  \end{array} \right.$$

Show that $T(K)\subset K$, that $T$ is an isometry from $K$ to $K$, and that $T$ does not have a fixed point in $K$ (ie there is no $f\in K$ such that $Tf=f$).

---

As $0\leq f\leq 2$, we know that $min\{2f(2t),2\} \text{ and } max\{0,2f(2t-1)-2\}$ are valued between $0$ and $2$. We also know that if $0\leq t\leq 1/2$, then $f(2t)$ is going to cover the entire range $[f(0),f(1)]$ and if if $1/2\lt t\lt 1$ then $f(2t-1)$ also covers the entire range $[f(0),f(1)]$.

These observations are about all I can get right now... I am pretty unsure how to attack the problem as a whole, other than these initial observations. Help would be greatly appreciated.